# How can I install Ubuntu from a USB drive on a Gateway laptop after getting a blank screen?

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, usb, windows-10

I bought a new Gateway GWTN156-1GR laptop and want to destroy Windows (without ever setting it up) and install Ubuntu from an installation flash drive that I have successfully used multiple times.

I've managed to rearrange the boot options and have gotten to the screen with the installation menu (it calls itself `GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.1`). But choosing any of "Try Ubuntu without installing," "Install Ubuntu," or "OEM install (for manufacturers)" sends me to a blank screen (no blinking cursor or anything) that, as far as I can tell, never progresses.

I don't know what else to try from here; I've found various posts elsewhere indicating that Gateway makes it especially difficult to do this, so maybe I'm just out of luck, but if that's the case I at least want confirmation.

Comment: There might be problems with the graphics driver. What graphics processor (chip/card) is there?

Comment: I can't find anything specific on the BIOS screen about graphics; it seems to be integrated with the CPU, which is an Intel Core i5-1035G1.

Comment: Then I think there might be some other problem because Intel graphics will usually work with Ubuntu at least if it is new enough. Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? The grub version seems old, and it makes me think that you are trying with an old (maybe too old) version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Indeed, I have 16.04 on the flash drive. Do you think making a new installation drive with 20.04 might help? (I was going to do this before posting the question, but then my  "that I have successfully used multiple times" wouldn't have been true.)

Comment: Yes, 20.04.2 LTS will be more likely to succeed in a computer with new hardware.

Comment: I will try that and let you know how it goes. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126898/discussion-between-joshua-schwartz-and-sudodus).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: I don't think so…my solution was just erasing the flash drive and remaking it with a release that wasn't obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

Elementary: use an up-to-date installation medium and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. It can help other users :-)